# Execute for loop but make it show just one of the elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem with JS.
I have a gallery items, each item has background, play icon and title, i decided to tell CSS display none of the title and icon and only when i go with my mouse over the item (hover) the title and the icon will show up, i tried to use 'for' and it works but it show up every one of the titles and icons each time i go over random item with my mouse.

```
  const img_block = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block');
  const play_butt = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block-iconplay');
  const text_img = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block-title');
    
    
    for (img of img_block) {
        img.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease';
        
        img.onmouseover = function MouseOverImg() {
            for (play of play_butt) {
                play.style.display = 'block';
                play.classList.add('fade-in');
            }
            for (text of text_img) {
                text.style.display = 'block';
                text.classList.add('fade-in');
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (img of img_block) {
        img.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease';
        
        img.onmouseout = function MouseOutImg() {
            for (play of play_butt) {
                play.style.display = 'none';
            }
            for (text of text_img) {
                text.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out figure how to make each item show its specific title and icon and not all of them at once?

EDIT:
HTML structure:

```
    <div class="gallery-item-block">
            
            <div style="background-image:url('https://local/65988.jpg')" class="gallery-item-block-img nes"></div>
            <div class="gallery-item-block-iconplay fade-in" style="display: none;" bis_skin_checked="1">
                <i class="gallery-item-block-iconplay-box-icon fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item-block-title fade-in" style="display: none;" bis_skin_checked="1">
                <p class="gallery-item-block-title-box-text">
                    <span>
                     Title <br> 08:80
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Picture of visual example i want to achieve (assume that title and icon display none):
[image]

Comment: Would help to see your html structure.

Comment: @ThomasFrank Added HTML and Picture Example

Answer (score 1):

I would use two delegated event handlers, they can use the same basic function that first checks to see if the mouse is over or out on a gallery-item-block, the grabs the playBtn and text inside that block...

```
const img_block = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block');

function mouseOverAndOut(e, out = false) {
  let img = e.target.closest('.gallery-item-block');
  if (!img) { return; }
  let playBtn = img.querySelector('.gallery-item-block-iconplay');
  let text = img.querySelector('.gallery-item-block-title');
  let display = out ? 'none' : 'block', addRemove = out ? 'remove' : 'add';
  [playBtn, text].forEach(x =>
    x.style.display = display && x.classList[addRemove]('fade-in'));
}

document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', e => mouseOverAndOut(e));
document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', e => mouseOverAndOut(e, true));

for (img of img_block) {
  img.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease';
}
```

If I understand the additional question in your comment to this answer correctly you muiltiple text or playBtn elements in on of the '.gallery-item-blocks'?

If so change the code slightly:

```
const img_block = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block');

function mouseOverAndOut(e, out = false) {
  let img = e.target.closest('.gallery-item-block');
  if (!img) { return; }
  let playBtns = img.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block-iconplay');
  let texts = img.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item-block-title');
  let display = out ? 'none' : 'block', addRemove = out ? 'remove' : 'add';
  [...playBtns, ...texts].forEach(x =>
    x.style.display = display && x.classList[addRemove]('fade-in'));
}

document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', e => mouseOverAndOut(e));
document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', e => mouseOverAndOut(e, true));

for (img of img_block) {
  img.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease';
}
```

Comment: What if i have multi querySelectors i mean many divs like i mentioned as a node, this structure i added is one of 4 i have i a row, so thats why i wrote querySelectorAll.

Comment: Answered by editing the answer :)

Comment: I'm trying to get a hang of this code section about hour and it seems really fine but actually its not working :\ I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood what you wanted to do then? Not more btns and text inside the same 'gallery-item-block'?

Did the first  part of the code work? (Before your extra question)

Comment: Must stop coding for today, but will have a new look tomorrow.